# ¿como puedo pasar un arreglo a través de un helper button_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tengo un listado de estados y necesito seleccionar varios de esos estados, pero no logro pasarlo a través del helper button_to a la acción correspondiente.

*Adjunto mi código:*

**Routes:**

```
get 'tableros/procesar/:ids'    => 'tableros#procesar',    as: 'procesar'
```

**Controlador:**

```
def estados
  @estados = Estado.all.order("id ASC")
  @estado_ids = []
end

def procesar
    puts params[:ids].inspect
    # alguna lógica
end
```

**Vista:**

```
<h1>Estados</h1>
<%= button_to 'Procesar', procesar_path(@estado_ids), :class => "btn btn-info", method: :get  %>
<% @estados.each do |estado| %>
  <div class = "cuadro">
    <%= button_to "#{estado.nombre}", municipios_path(estado), :class => "btn btn-info", :style => "width: 180px;", method: :get %>
    <%= check_box_tag "@estado_ids[]", estado.id %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Se que mi código está incompleto, pero no encuentro nada en Internet que me pueda servir.

*¿alguna idea como puedo salir de este atolladero?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que pasando `ids` como parámetro:

```
<%= button_to 'Procesar', procesar_path(ids: @estado_ids), :class => "btn btn-info", method: :get  %>
```

y en tus archivos de rutas remover `:ids`:

```
get 'tableros/procesar'    => 'tableros#procesar',    as: 'procesar'
```

debería funcionar.

Comment: Me llega nil en la accion

Comment: Estaba poniendo mal la variable en el controlador, si me trae los valores que necesito.